# Getting ASP.NET Temp file name

Tags: c#, asp.net

For one of my requirement, i want to get the temp file name from temp directory.

**Say for Eg:** temp file name is as in temp dir "**filename.aspx.88deeb5b.COMPILED**".

I am able to get this when i run/debug the solution using below class(s)

```
var path = System.Web.VirtualPath.Create("/ABC/filename.aspx");
string key = System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetCacheKeyFromVirtualPathInternal(path);
```

So the key returns with like "filename.aspx.88deeb5b". This is what i want to get. am getting this using immediate window.

But this is accessible during run/debug time only (from immediate window). 
When i started put these lines in my class file, am not able to create the "VirtualPath.create()" object as well as "GetCacheKeyFromVirtualPathInternal" object. I see that VirtualPath is an sealed class and GetCacheKeyFromVirtualPathInternal is a method from BuildManager sealed class.

Is there a way to get the key as i expected from my class file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the ASP.Net Temporary file name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45149960/how-to-get-the-asp-net-temporary-file-name)

Comment: Yes, Deleted the old thread.